# Inline scalar functions: real or vaporware?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

What is the correct syntax to create an **inline scalar function** in SQL Server?

Books Online, in the [Types of Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) chapter (2005 and up), talks about Inline Scalar Functions as if they exist and as if no `BEGIN...END` block is required (in contrast with multiline functions):

> For an inline scalar function, there is no function body; the scalar
>   value is the result of a single statement. For a multistatement scalar function, the function body, defined in a BEGIN...END block, contains a series of Transact-SQL statements that return the single value.

I also noticed a row for *"IS: inline scalar function"* in the list of object types in the spt_values table:

```
SELECT name
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'O9T'
AND name LIKE '%function%'
```

I have tried to create such a function with no success:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddOne(@n int) RETURNS int
AS
    RETURN @n + 1
```

The error message is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure AddOne, Line 3 Incorrect syntax
>   near 'RETURN'.

Am I missing something or is there an error in Books Online?

Comment: I'm not seeing how either BOL for CREATE FUNCTION nor the link you referenced implies you don't need BEGIN..END blocks.  I think you're mis-reading something.

Comment: To clarify, I would like to create a function of type 'IS' and not 'FN' or 'TF'.

Comment: And what is meant by "For an inline scalar function, there is no function body"?

Comment: It is interesting to note that this still exists in the 2012 docs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: The good people at Internet Archive got it in writing, although it does say "This documentation is for preview only, and is subject to change in later releases.":  https://web.archive.org/web/20111223173828/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499(v=SQL.110).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, AFAIK, none exist (not even in the hidden [**mssqlsystemresource**] database) and there's no syntax to create one.  So it appears that this is something that Microsoft must have anticipated in the run-up to SQL Server 2005 by adding a type for it (and doc!), but never actually implemented for some reason.

Though it is one of the single most requested features for all of Ms Sql Server.  Primarily because the default UDF's are so slow and we end up having to back-end ITVF's to get the same effect. (difficult and clumsy, but it works).

Comment: Looks like they are nearly here http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol11/p432-ramachandra.pdf

Comment: @MartinSmith WOW!  So they decided to fix *all* scalar functions instead of just implementing inline scalar functions?  I have to admit, it sounds awesome, but it still seems like they could have given us the inline as a cheap and easy interim option.

Comment: Why give an interim option when the feature is available to try out already? Please see my answer below! :)

Comment: Official MSDN Documentation for the new INLINE Scalar UDF'S!!: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=azuresqldb-current

Answer (score 4):

Correct, there is no such thing as a inline scalar function.  One can be "simulated" by using an inline-TVF, however, the syntax of any "clients" will need to change.
1) create he function:

```
    create function dbo.AddOne(@input int) returns table as return (select @input + 1 as value);
```

2) in the "client" code, do this...

```
    (select value from dbo.AddOne(Column)) as ColumnPlusOne
```

An now you have a functioning inline scalar function.

I've had to do this to replace a lot of scalar UDFs in my client code that looked like this...

```
create function dbo.GetLookupID(@code varchar(50)) returns int
as
begin
    declare @return int;
    select @return = LookupID from dbo.Lookups where Code = @code;
    return @return;
end;
```

I tried fixing it by removing the variable...

```
create function dbo.GetLookupID(@code varchar(50)) returns int
as
begin
    return (select LookupID from dbo.Lookups where Code = @code);
end;
```

That was an improvement, however, there was still an unpleasant performance hit.  When I changed to the iTVF and changed the calling convention.... it got much better.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with SQL Server 2019 CTP2.1, there is a new feature called "Scalar UDF inlining" which can automatically inline scalar UDFs when certain preconditions are satisfied.

The official blog post introducing the feature is here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/11/07/introducing-scalar-udf-inlining/

Detailed documentation that describes the feature is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=azuresqldb-current

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same thing. That sentence seems to be the only reference to "inline scalar functions". [This article](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions) claims that inline table-valued functions can be fast enough to do the job.